# The "which" command won't work in PHP

Tags: php, mercurial, shell-exec

I have two remote servers that need to have a certain codebase in sync. I have it all set up on the first, but while setting it up on the second, I ran into a problem:

They don't have `hg` installed in the same location. I can't just run `hg <command>` because it returns the error:

> sh: hg: command not found

So I had been using the full path, but that won't work with two separate `hg` locations.

I thought it would be clever to run `which hg` and use the path from the response, so here's the new code:

```
$hg = trim(`which hg`, "\n");
$output = `{$hg} pull -u`
```

But `$hg` is `NULL`, so that doesn't work! I can ssh into the 2nd server and see that `which hg` definitely does work. I even appended `2>> path/to/log` to see if there were any errors with the `which` command, but there was not. I made sure it was writing to the log, so it wasn't related to that.

I am not running in safe mode, and I am definitely allowed to run `shell_exec` because other commands work.

I know I could just create a symlink so they both had the same path and just hardcode the path, but it's driving me crazy why `shell_exec('which hg')` isn't working!!!

Comment: Via a POST triggered by BitBucket.org when I push to my repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which hg` will only work if `hg` is already in your path, otherwise it will return the empty string.

Obviously this is not what you want, since if it were already in your path, you could just use `hg`.

If you're using many machines with different configs, you could just create a `bin` directory in your home directory, add it to your path and make links to the commands you need in that directory. That will allow you to use the same commands on all machines.

For PHP, you'd need to put it in a directory accessible to the web server (but preferably outside the document root), besides that, you can use the same technique there by giving an absolute path to the common directory where you created your links.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What a good solution? Is there a way to add `hg` 's path to my path for PHP to look in, like in my php.ini or something, so it's different for each server?

Comment: @CWSpear Added some ore info on a possible solution.

Comment: Well, since other stuff was working, `/usr/bin/` was obviously in my path, so I created symlinks for `hg` in `/usr/bin/`. That's pretty much what you said, just not in the home dir. Is that okay? Anything I'm missing that doesn't make that okay?

Comment: @CWSpear No, as long as you're root on the machine, that should work just fine. Sometimes `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt` are used for that to be able to easier know which are system binaries vs. local tweaks, but that's more of a technicality.

Comment: Great, thank you. Everything's working great. With one push, two (well, three if you count local) servers all in sync.

Answer (score 0):

try

`shell_exec('/usr/bin/which hg');`

instead. `$PATH` may not be set and that is a typical location of `which`

Comment: `which which` worked, so I don't think that's it. It also probably would have resulted an error like when I tried to use `hg`.